# Ford Sync problem

Tags: ford, fusion, bluetooth, sync

I have a 2014 ford fusion se with the regular radio,media,phone set up. Recently I haven't been able to use the Bluetooth, or phone option at all, even though I could prior to this. Nothing catastrophic has happened to cause it to do this. I have restarted my phone, forgot the Bluetooth on my phone, master reset the cars radio. Even pulled the fuses and disconnected the battery and nothing has worked. I've seen quite a few people have the same problem with the common tell-tale sign of it going back to the radio whenever you click on media. I was wondering if replacing the "sync module" might fix this, my part # is DS7T-14B428-AG (they are different for different car models although they look the same. Has anyone had this problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently just fixed this. I went to a car junkyard, found my generation of ford fusion and took out the Sync Module, it is a Black rectangular box underneath the dash you can get to it from the driver and passenger side of the car. I then took out my old one and replaced it with the new one. Just had to add my phone from the setting, and good as new. The new Sync module didn't have the same part number as mine but it still worked.